# Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost... TCP error code 10061

Tags: windows-services, nettcpbinding, net.tcp, wcf

Referring to a video [tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdebugmode.net%2F2010%2F06%2F16%2Fvideowcfnetcpinwindowsservice%2F&rct=j&q=hosting%20wcf%20in%20windows%20service%20example%20nettcpbinding&ei=boYlTuDwNI_PrQf08dW1CQ&usg=AFQjCNHLIlo3nOeav1O5NzNtIAVxQ6gywQ&cad=rja) about WCF service in windows service,i have created a sample WCF service and hosted that Service with netTcpBinding in Windows Service.(since i want this WCF service to run as windows service)

Its a simple service which adds/deletes/loads employee details, and is consumed by a windows forms application.that worked fine,when i build the whole solution(consisting wcf service + windows service + client app), however when i wanted to verify that my client isn't directly referring to the project in the solution, so i excluded both the services(wcf+windows) from my solution. it stopped working throwing an error, reading:

Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8010/EmployeeService.Service1/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0180000. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8010.

Important point that might help to answer:

- WCF service and windows service have identical app.config
- Windows service is running as a service

*this is my client app.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings>
                <netTcpBinding>
                    <binding name="netTcpEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
                        transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                            enabled="false" />
                        <security mode="Transport">
                          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                        </security>
                    </binding>
                </netTcpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <client>
                <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8010/EmployeeService.Service1/"
                    binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpEndPoint"
                    contract="Service1.IService1" name="netTcpEndPoint">
                    <identity>
                        <userPrincipalName value="user@company.com" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
            </client>
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself, hope it helps other looking for it...

I found that event of worker_DoWork() is not triggered, so add worker.RunWorkerAsync(); as shown in the code below to your windows service

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{                    
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);                
}
```

Delete the Service reference from client project, add it again, since it makes changes to your app.config file.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quickie note that may help some folk:

This error came up between two computers that controlled a Perkin Elmer - Thermo Fisher Scientific Liquid Handling apparatus (robot).

McAfee Antivirus was interfering with their communication and uninstalling McAfee banished the error.
MS Security Essentials Antivirus did NOT interfere.

Comment: With completely different hardware, disabling the firewall and anti-virus checking stopped TCP error code 10061 for me. This is not a long-term solution, but allowed me to proceed.